# Get exception when I want to catch a large number of cards in list

Tags: manatee.trello

@gregdennis I wrote this code to catch all cards in one list:

```
var requestList = new List("556be3f8e4a6b530c795db6d");
var cardsCount = requestList.Cards.Filter(CardFilter.All).ToList();
```

I test this in URL with this:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/lists/556be3f8e4a6b530c795db6d/cards?filter=all&key=[myke]&token=[mytoken]
```

and I got the correct answer but with Manatee this Exception has thrown:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Inner Exception: Expected ','. Path: '$[849].name'
full stack:

```
    System.AggregateException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=Manatee.Trello
  StackTrace:
       at Manatee.Trello.Internal.ExceptionHandling.DebugLog.Error(Exception e, Boolean shouldThrow) in C:\Users\gregd\OneDrive\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello\Internal\ExceptionHandling\DebugLog.cs:line 26
       at Manatee.Trello.Internal.DataAccess.JsonRepository.ValidateResponse(IRestRequest request) in C:\Users\gregd\OneDrive\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello\Internal\DataAccess\JsonRepository.cs:line 62
       at Manatee.Trello.Internal.DataAccess.JsonRepository.Execute[T](TrelloAuthorization auth, Endpoint endpoint, IDictionary`2 parameters) in C:\Users\gregd\OneDrive\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello\Internal\DataAccess\JsonRepository.cs:line 28
       at Manatee.Trello.ReadOnlyCardCollection.Update() in C:\Users\gregd\OneDrive\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello\CardCollection.cs:line 64
       at Manatee.Trello.ReadOnlyCollection`1.GetEnumerator() in C:\Users\gregd\OneDrive\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello\ReadOnlyCollection.cs:line 58
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at OrchidTrello.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Projects\Trello API\OrchidTrello\OrchidTrello\Program.cs:line 25
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146232828
       Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
            at Manatee.Trello.WebApi.WebApiJsonFormatter.Deserialize(Type type, String content) in C:\Users\gregd\OneDrive\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello.WebApi\WebApiJsonFormatter.cs:line 69
            at Manatee.Trello.WebApi.WebApiJsonFormatter.Read(Type type, Stream readStream) in C:\Users\gregd\OneDrive\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello.WebApi\WebApiJsonFormatter.cs:line 55
            at Manatee.Trello.WebApi.WebApiJsonFormatter.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<ReadFromStreamAsync>b__0() in C:\Users\gregd\OneDrive\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello.WebApi\WebApiJsonFormatter.cs:line 42
            at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
            at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.<ReadAsAsyncCore>d__0`1.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
            at Manatee.Trello.WebApi.WebApiClient.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\gregd\OneDrive\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello.WebApi\WebApiClient.cs:line 98
       InnerException: 
            HResult=-2146233088
            Message=Expected ','. Path: '$[944].name'
            Path=$[944].name
            Source=Manatee.Json
            StackTrace:
                 at Manatee.Json.Parsing.JsonParser.Parse(String source) in C:\Users\gregd\OneDrive\Projects\Manatee.Json\Manatee.Json\Parsing\JsonParser.cs:line 51
                 at Manatee.Json.JsonValue.Parse(String source) in C:\Users\gregd\OneDrive\Projects\Manatee.Json\Manatee.Json\JsonValue.cs:line 343
                 at Manatee.Trello.ManateeJson.ManateeSerializer.Deserialize[T](String content) in C:\Users\gregd\OneDrive\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello.ManateeJson\ManateeSerializer.cs:line 74
            InnerException:
```

this is my version:

```
<package id="Manatee.Json" version="5.2.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Manatee.Trello" version="1.15.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Manatee.Trello.ManateeJson" version="1.7.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Manatee.Trello.WebApi" version="1.0.6" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure that tagging in questions works.  Even so, it's *greg**s**dennis.* ;P

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  Could you paste in the full error message and the stack trace, please?  Also, are you using the latest version of the library?

Comment: Please edit the question and include your responses there.

Comment: excuse me for wrong tagging! I Edit my question with all things

Comment: It looks like there's a JSON parse issue.  Would you please create an issue on my repo on GitHub? If you can, please also attach the JSON you get in the web response.  If it contains sensitive info, I'll provide my email there.  Thanks.

Comment: sure. how can I find your Email address?

Comment: Please create the issue in github, I'll provide it there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in Manatee.Json.  Please download the latest version (v5.2.1 or higher) to resolve the issue.